Are bodies in fluids stressed?
If air applies pressure isotropically in all directions normal and into the object, then does it mean that anything in air is stressed by the air pressure? I know that the pressure is all the same in every direction so there is no net force, but this does not mean that stress is zero? If yes, then is it also strained like contracted a little bit compared to zero pressure? How we are not feeling this stress? Because a beam is also static but it is stressed by forces applied to it and it can feel the stress (strained).

In a static fluid, and in the absence of body forces like gravity, the pressure can be the same throughout the fluid. The pressure can compress (strain) a body submerged in the fluid.

Ok then the atmospheric pressure is stressing us? So every m^2 of our body feeling 1atm stress and we not feeling it ? I know the net force is zero , but try comprising your skin with 10^5 pascals , how are not feeling this? To be specific i am talking about the air which is around us not fluids in general

"...how are not feeling this?" That seems to be  a question about human physiology, not physics. How are you able to breath without thinking about each breath you take? How are you able to open your eyes without feeling pain, but your skin feels pain from too much exposure to sunlight?

(Anyways, this website is not a discussion forum; you are not supposed to use the comments for extending your questions beyond the original question you posted. If you want to discuss try the chat section.)

Yes, bodies immersed in fluids that exert pressure are both stressed and strained (compressed). But the strain is very small.
At a pressure of 1 atmosphere, the actual change in size is very small for most liquids and solids. The bulk modulus of water is $2.2 \times 10^9 \mathrm{Pa}$. The pressure of the atmosphere is $1 \times 10^5 \mathrm{Pa}$. That means that a blob of water (such as you) is reduced in size by only 0.005% by the pressure of the atmosphere.
Humans can withstand much higher pressures. The highest I am aware of is 70 atmospheres, achieved in a hyperbaric chamber as part of the Hydra 10 experiment [1]. The "divers" (they were not actually underwater) in this experiment lived at pressures at or above 65 atmospheres for 5 consecutive days. Even at these high pressures, the physical compression of their bodies was not the limiting factor. The problem was neural dysfunction from highly concentrated helium. To mitigate this, hydrogen was mixed into the gas.
Of course, if only part of your body is subject to high pressure, the strain will be significantly greater, and you will definitely feel it. You can think of these effects like squeezing a balloon that is completely full of water. You cannot change the volume of the balloon noticeably, even with lots of pressure. If you apply pressure unevenly across the balloon, you can change its shape. If the balloon had sensors in its "skin," it could detect the change in shape. However, if you compress it completely evenly on all sides, you will not change its shape. The sensors in its skin will not detect a change in shape unless they are sensitive enough to detect the extremely small (0.005%/atm) compression.
The part of your body that is most sensitive to pressure changes is your ear, because there is air trapped in there. Unlike water, air is very easy to compress, so if you are subjected to increased atmospheric pressure, your eardrum will be significantly strained, and you will feel that. By doing the Valsalva maneuver, you can open a tube that lets the pressurized outside air into your ear, after which essentially all the strain is relieved and you no longer feel anything.
[1] Gardette et al., "Hydra 10: A 701 msw onshore record dive using 'hydreliox'", *Proceedings of the XIXth Annual Meeting of EUBS 1993 (https://diving-rov-specialists.com/index_htm_files/scient-b_24-gardette-jym-eubs-1993-hydra10.pdf)

Very nice, that’s what i was looking for , thank you

The inward stress pushes an object's molecules closer together.  These molecules press back against each other and then against the surrounding air.  A more complex system is the body.  Fluids within a skin cell press outward against this inward stress as that inward stress moves the molecules within the cell closer together.  This also happens with body fluids pressing against the inside of the skin.  A cell within a vacuum for any significant length of time will explode because the inward stress from the environment is not there to counter the outward stress from the compressed materials within.  A balloon with a vary small amount of air sealed within will inflate in a vacuum.  That air within begins at air pressure, pushing out against the balloon.  When the outside air is removed, the outward stress from the air contained within the balloon is no longer balanced by the inward stress from air around the balloon.
